# Android IP fetching

Tags: android

we are doing a chat application using android 2.3.3 as a project, when we open the application we need to fetch the IP address automatically through code and send it to the server with status.How it can be done. We 'll be grateful for any help regarding this topic.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tak a look here [Get IP address](http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html)

And don't forget to add the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to the manifest

Answer (score 1):

Why would you send the IP to the server? The server can get the IP when the client connect?

Normally the client would have to know the IP to the server and connect to it. Under some circumstances it could be hard or impossible to tell what IP it will get when it reaches the server (NAT firewalls, proxies, multiple networking devices such as 3G, wifi etc.).

To list all IP addresses registered on your Android device you could do (code from http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I suggest that you read up on client/server architectures. There are several guides on this topic.

http://pguides.net/java/tcp-client-server-chat

http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html